# How do I type a tuple type as a mapped object type or how can I construct an object type from a list of keys?

Tags: typescript

Okay, so I have a system where I use attributes in the form of symbols.

```
const A = Symbol.for(":a")
const B = Symbol.for(":b")
const C = Symbol.for(":c")

interface Attributes {
  [A]: string
  [B]: number
  [C]: boolean
}

const pattern_1 = [A, B]
const pattern_2 = [B, C]
```

I need a function that can infer the object type:

- `{ [A]: string, [B]: number }` from `pattern_1` `[A, B]`
- `{ [B]: number, [C]: boolean }` from `pattern_2` `[B, C]`

I have gotten this far

```
type AttributeKeys ReadonlyArray<keyof Attributes>

declare function pattern<Pattern extends AttributeKeys>(...attrs: Pattern): Pattern

const PATTERN = pattern(A, B) // inferred type is [typeof A, typeof B]
```

What I cannot do, is to change the tuple type into an object. In the next step I want it to infer that I will return a an object with the keys from the array as keys in a new object type. I want the type of the keys to match that which is declared in Attributes. This is the farthest I've been able to come:

```
declare function pull1<T>(pattern: T): { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Attributes ? Attributes[K] : never }

const entity1 = pull1(PATTERN) // inferred type is [never, never]

declare function pull2<T>(pattern: T): { [K in keyof Attributes]: K extends T ? Attributes[K] : never }

const entity2 = pull2(PATTERN) // inferred type is { [A]: never, [B]: never, [C]: never }
```

I cannot get this to work, need help! Here's a [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgjAvDAygTwLYCMQBsB0AZiAE4AUARAFwCGFAlAFCiSwBCSqmOBx51WBs3DQYAYU7pseIqUpVgQxgEswUAKYlCNYOvhQoJZVgCuGiDADejGLZgBtOAF0qMaEbABzG3ftsXMGAm2Jo%20tvZiATh46jRgjAC%20jIwAJurAuDQkeoQmYMBQyuAwAA40BppgADwACuUaJGAw6gAeGmApFgBKsSnguGhwJCQ0aFUA1upoIIT6hsZm6hAAfMtk%20Bv1JBCudRWN9Lv1lcksojVwACqXAKJdAHKcZftgZHAANDBs9DAA9L8wVSETTZFIwKBoEp6ZQWewQqEzeCfeHqRH%20ZJpDJZHJ5ApFJolEy4XAARiqlzWzwaYFcl0OVgcAGlAU1JtNZpcAszWu1OjA2Yi4AYjKZzDAAPxzEWLCD2RlOGCuMDqABumhgSWErGaamUEJJTyJpLIF2ud3uP3%20LOBw3UYJRgNhyrVJE%20zs0Tgx6Uy2RguXyhWKhOJACZyZTjo1afTLEyWfypoLhQtzFzmm11B0LJcJVKU0s5Qqlar1ZqzrBM4UISHDaGTVdbg9LQCgSC7eDIdCLLHHAF3a6HP5iy7PhE%20yWSBrGEA) if any one think they can crack it.

PS. I have to use symbols but the rest is just things I've tried. If there's a better way please share!

Comment: Where does the function get the property *values* from? An object's properties don't just have types, they have values as well. Or did you just want a mapped type, not a function?

Comment: Just a mapped type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `Pick` predefined mapped types:

```
declare function pull2<T extends Array<keyof Attributes>>(pattern: T): Pick<Attributes, T[number]>

const entity2 = pull2(PATTERN)
let a = entity2[A] // string
let b = entity2[B] // number
entity2[C] // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-0CwSwoQtVsituaw0YQA)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!